# Ways to change an explicit function into a pure function

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

I'm trying to use `FixedPoint` to solve a transcendental equations, but the first argument of the `FixedPoint` should be a pure function, But the function I have to use is an explicit function from a lot of preceeding symbolic calculations and is very complicated, e.g.,

```
func=-HankelH1[1, 0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]] ((1/(
  57.641231 - \[Beta]^2))
  1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
    0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] ((
     1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
       0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] HankelH1[1, 
       0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]])/(27.415568 - \[Beta]^2) - (
     1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
       0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] HankelH1[1, 
       0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]])/(57.641231 - \[Beta]^2))
```

My failed effort is to use `Function[\[Beta],func]&`, but it seems the value of func doesn't get into the Function, because of scoping problem I think.

Is there any clever way to change functions like this to be a pure function??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use explicit `Function`, you don't need `&`. That would be `Function@Function...`

Try `Function[\[Beta], Evaluate@func]`. The `Evaluate` is because otherwise `func` would only get evaluated AFTER replacing `\[Beta]` with the values when doing, e.g, `Function[\[Beta], func][3.]`, so they just won`t be replaced because they are not there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to worry about `Function` in this question at all. Instead, you could just take your expression `func` with the parameter `\[Beta]` and define a new function as follows:

```
f[\[Beta]_] = func
```

Here I used a `=` instead of an `:=` to get the evaluated expression `func` as the replacement for the pattern `f[\[Beta]_]`, where `\[Beta]_` with an underscore names the pattern that is then used as the value for `\[Beta]` on the righthand side.

Now you should be able to use `f` in the `FixedPoint` like this

```
FixedPoint[f, startingValue]
```

All that is really needed for `FixedPoint` is that the first argument has to have a "slot" into which the iterated results can be inserted. You can define that "slot" using `Function`, using `#...&` or by the means I chose. The latter is the simplest in this case where an expression already exists that has the desired variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to cope with this problem, albeit not so elegant.

```
    func=-HankelH1[1, 0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]] ((1/(
      57.641231 - \[Beta]^2))
      1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
        0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] ((
         1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
           0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] HankelH1[1, 
           0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]])/(27.415568 - \[Beta]^2) - (
         1.6666667 \[Beta] BesselJ[1, 
           0.6 Sqrt[57.641231 - \[Beta]^2]] HankelH1[1, 
           0.6 Sqrt[27.415568 - \[Beta]^2]])/(57.641231 - \[Beta]^2));

    f=(Evaluate[func/.\[Beta]->#])&;
```

But I'm still waiting for a more clever way.

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding something. You do not need to use a pure function in `FixedPoint`. That's just something people do for convenience when they don't want to give a function a separate name. Now you _are_ giving a function a separate name (`f`), but trying hard to make it look like a pure function, which is completely unnecessary. All you need to do is to define a "function" with a slot from the **expression** `func` that you have. Note that `func` is not an "explicit function" as you call it. It has no function slots.

Comment: Is just defining `func[\[Beta]_] = ...` and then using `FixedPoint[func,x0]` not an option ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, thank you.+1